# Dell XPS 17: Weird console/firefox issue as I type characters, where the cursor jumps back in time - but only with an external monitor attached

Tags: multiple-monitors, xorg, display, cursor, flicker

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 with the latest updates as of today, on a Dell XPS 9710 (late 2021, early 2022 model) laptop with the UHD 17" LCD screen.

I have a second monitor, a Dell P2715Q 4-K monitor connected via HDMI (or DisplayPort, doesn't seem to matter for this issue).

I'm using the i3 window manager, and whatever Xorg config Ubuntu 22.04 ships with, with gdm.

The problem is that when I type in, say, an XTerm or URxvt, or even this text-entry field in Firefox, **on the laptop screen**, there is a noticeable "time warp", where the screen sometimes reverts back in time to show the state a few milliseconds earlier. I know this sounds weird, so let me explain - normally if I'm typing a line in, say, a URxvt terminal I'd expect to see the cursor move uniformly from left to write - as characters are typed, the block cursor (or line cursor in Firefox) moves one space to the right, and the entered character appears where the cursor *was*. But what I see is the cursor momentarily jumping back, to the left, usually one or two characters, and the mostly recently typed character or two disappearing momentarily. Then a fraction of a second later, it's all as it should be.

In the worst case, I've seen entire words I've typed momentarily disappear, and then reappear again!

The overall effect is one of severe flickering of the displayed characters, around the cursor only, as I type.

It's almost as if the buffering of the screen is getting messed up, and old video card buffers are being displayed mistakenly, or in the wrong order. But I really don't know what is going on.

But if I type in a window on the external monitor, it's solid, no flickering or jumping-back-cursor at all.

From what I've managed to ascertain, it only happens (on the laptop screen) when I'm using dual monitors. If I disconnect my external monitor and switch (via arandr or xrandr) back to single-screen (the laptop screen), this weird time-warping behaviour goes away and typing is "solid" again.

I'm using `autorandr` with this config (DisplayPort), in case that helps:

```
output DP-2
off
output DP-3
off
output DP-4
off
output DP-1
crtc 1
mode 3840x2160
pos 3840x0
rate 60.00
transform 1.250000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,1.250000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,1.000000
output eDP-1
crtc 0
mode 3840x2400
pos 0x300
primary
rate 59.99
```

Any idea what is going on? It's not a show-stopper, but it's so infuriating!

Comment: I can add that the mouse cursor often flickers on/off rapidly, on the laptop screen only.

Comment: This issue has now been seen on two XPS 17 (2021) and an XPS 15 (2022), with Ubuntu 22.04 and Arch Linux.

Answer (score 0):

After some time, I stumbled across the i915 "Panel Self Refresh" feature, which is enabled by default and can cause visual issues on Dell laptop screens (and other brands too).

Putting `i915.enable_psr=0` on the end of my kernel command-line (v5.15) and rebooting seems to have resolved the issue for me. It remains effective after resuming from hibernation too.

This has definitely cleaned up the flickering text cursor, and so far the mouse cursor also looks clean, but time will tell...